# Odd new "RegMail" mailbox in Apple Mail (9.2)

Tags: email

A few days ago I had a new mailbox in Apple Mail, which I did not create but which is listed under my on-line account with GMX.

The mailbox is called "RegMail", it isn't on GMX and it doesn't delete. If I delete the mailbox from ~/Library.Mail/. it comes back. Nothing shows up under a virus scan and it contains no emails. Rebuild and sync do not get rid of it.

Anyone else seen this? How to get rid?

D

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced this issue. It doesn't seem to be anything to worry about though. I've logged into GMX, and the folder doesn't exist there, which means it's a local issue, possibly how the email client connects. I'm using Aqua Mail.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using Apple Mail and Airmail. Both show the rogue mailbox. It does not exist on GMX and I can't delete it. Oddly, I think it has something to do with Google (the new owners of GMX) wanting to peddle gmail (hence Re gMail). Can';t be bothered to report it to GMX just so they can write back saying I should consult the FAQ. Fastmail adopted this approach to lazy customer service this and I closed my account. I may well give GMX their marching orders, I cannot abide this kind of stupidity.

Comment: I might get another insulting badge from SU though, so I suppose I may have to flip them the bird again. Wake up lads; support good, arrogance bad, get on with the job you get paid for.